# How to open a page from App.xaml.cs if not open already

Tags: xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

I have a Xaml.Forms app that uses FreshMVVM. I open a certain page from app.xaml.cs like this:

```
        Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            var navService = FreshIOC.Container.Resolve<IFreshNavigationService>(FreshMvvm.Constants.DefaultNavigationServiceName);
            Page page = FreshPageModelResolver.ResolvePageModel<SomePageModel>();
            await navService.PushPage(page, null);

    ...
        });
```

But I need to add a check to prevent doing this if this page is already open. How can I make such a check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a static bool value in the App class to check if the page has been opened:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static bool isPageOpened;
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }

    public void test()
    {

        if (App.isPageOpened = false)
        {
            Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                var navService = FreshIOC.Container.Resolve<IFreshNavigationService>(FreshMvvm.Constants.DefaultNavigationServiceName);
                Page page = FreshPageModelResolver.ResolvePageModel<SomePageModel>();

                App.isPageOpened = true;

                await navService.PushPage(page, null);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And in the page's OnDisappearing method, set the `isPageOpened` to false:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();

        App.isPageOpened = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I can use it. But may I ask first, isn't there a way to just find out which page is currently open?

Comment: No, I don't think there is such a way. You can have a try to check the navigation.childern[0].

Comment: @DavidShochet Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).